# make formula when in A1 number is 3 create like this =D$A1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for some solution that if I enter a certain number in a cell I can make a reference to a given cell.

in D3 i have number 4 and in A1 i want formula like this =$E$D3 and here I would like to get something that will get me a number from D3 and I will have this formula =$E$4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=INDEX($E:$E,$D$3)
```